# Why does this cause an oracle error? ORA-00907

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

This is driving me insane, can anyone help me understand why the following statements all return the following error?

```
create table JMS_PENDING_MESSAGE (id number primary key, queuex nvarchar2(200), messagex nclob(1000));
create table JMS_PENDING_MESSAGE (id number primary key, queuex nvarchar2(200), messagex nclob(10000));
create table JMS_PENDING_MESSAGE (id integer primary key, queuex nvarchar2(200), messagex nclob(10000));
```

And the error message:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Im running over JDBC using ojdbc5.jar if it makes a difference! Any help much appreciated, Im going insane

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CLOB is a CLOB (and, as o.k.w. points out, a NCLOB is an NCLOB).  You don't need to give it a size:

```
create table JMS_PENDING_MESSAGE 
    (id integer primary key, queuex nvarchar2(200), messagex nclob);
```

Comment: You meant "An NCLOB is a (C)LOB" :)